# cdk how to get appsync auto generated subdomain

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-appsync

after appsync api creation using cdk, im able to get the generated appsync domain by aws, this way:

```
const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(...);
const domain = api.graphqlUrl;
```

but this value's purpose is only to be saved as a ssm parameter because it is a cdk token, and it is not available at synth time.
now i need to grab the subdomain part of this value. after synth time, the value resolves as `https://XXXXX.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql` which is suitable for any service importing the parameter from ssm.

so question is: how do i can by using cdk, get only XXXXX part from full domain, and save it as ssm parameter too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the subdomain from the GraphQL URL with [CloudFormation intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html), which the CDK implements as [Fn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Fn.html).  Split the URL and select the item of interest:

```js
new ssm.StringParameter(this, 'SubdomainParam', {
  parameterName: 'ApiSubdomain',
  stringValue: cdk.Fn.select(
    0,
    cdk.Fn.split('.', cdk.Fn.select(1, cdk.Fn.split('https://', this.api.graphqlUrl)))
  ),
});
```

The actual parameter value resolves at deploy time, when the Url value becomes available.